# Log in from another php file with jquery load function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I would like to do a web site using Aptana IDE and xampp, and it has a few pages. Index page is where all users which does not log in the system and home is where all users which does log in the system must visit. I am very new to develop web site. Because of that I am changing a lot of and vital things during the development. An here my problem is began.

I have created log and sign pages separately using HTML5, CSS, Javascript, JQuery and Php. To achieve more quality service, decided to use also Ajax. These pages works correctly, log page can control validation with jquery

```
$('#login-form').validate({
//validation rules, messages and submitHandler(ajax code) goes here});
```

and with using ajax, it can communicate with php file and mysql database so can check whether the user is exist or not.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'log.php',
                data: strAjax, //username and password
                success: function(data) { //data is echoing from php file either as true or false
                    if(data) {
                        window.location.href = "home.php";
                    }
                    else {
                        //some error messages
                    }
                }
            });
```

Sign systems works like it and correctly. But I do not like the design of these pages because of emptiness. So in index file when user click log in button, the log file is showing inside a div with jquery load function.

```
$(".jumbotron").load("login.html").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(5000);
```

Same thing for sign system as well. For good looking, I am satisfied but... 
The whole system messed up. (I want to cry) I have to think before start to coding web site, very bad I know but this is my first complete web site. How can  achieve a system working properly in this way? I have searched some pages on the internet and they said that the ajax can not work across the pages or something like that. I am also new to stack overflow too, so some important thing will be forgotten. I can edit if you want more information.

Thank You and Regards...

EDIT 1:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>//sometext</h1>
    <p>//some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Firstly this is showing on the screen. And when the user press login button, jquery load function running which is above. And loads login.html which works properly by itself.

```
<form id="login-form" class="text-left">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lg_username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lg_username" name="username" placeholder="username"
                                   data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content=""
                                   value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lg_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="lg_password" name="password" placeholder="password" 
                                   data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group login-group-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="lg_remember" name="lg_remember">
                            <label for="lg_remember">remember</label>
                        </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="login-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The jquery validation works right. My rules are valid. If the inputs are ok upon my rules, it send me to home.php. I think ajax code can not work.

```
submitHandler: function() {
        var username = $('#lg_username').val();
            var password = $('#lg_password').val();
            var checkbox = $('#lg_remember').is(":checked");

            var strAjax = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&checkbox=" + checkbox;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'logDeneme.php',
                data: strAjax,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data) {
                        window.location.href = "home.php";
                    }
                    else {
                        //error message. but when this code run, always send to home page.
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
            }
```

This parts all works. It does not works inside index.php. My question is why and how to handle this!

Comment: What is the problem exactly? The only question I see is `How can achieve a system working properly in this way?` But what's not working?

Comment: Does not work properly. When I press the submit button, the url look like ...php?username=something&password=something, like GET method but nothing happen depends on username password. I think the ajax method does not work

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

Your form is submitting via a `GET` request because the JS is not getting called (see #2 below) and the HTML is likely declared like this:

```
<form action='log.php'>
[...]
</form>
```

You must specify `method='post'` to submit `POST` data.

**Problem 2**

Unless you're using [a jQuery plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) there is no `.validate` event for forms. You want to use [.submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Finally, make sure all your javascript is in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` or it won't execute at the right time. Look in the Firefox/Chrome developer console, it's a lifesaver for debugging.

Comment: But with submitHandler in jquery validation, Ajax is running. Actually this code works when I run it on the browser as login.php. But inside the index.php it does not

Comment: @kimdirbilmem I don't understand what you mean. Please post your full HTML/javascript for both pages (edit your OP).